# Rails 4.1: Creating routes by calling method in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want to create a method that, when called from a controller, will add a nested resource route with a given name that routes to a specific controller. For instance, this...

```
class Api::V1::FooController < ApplicationController
  has_users_route
end
```

...should be equivalent to...

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :foo do
      resources :users, controller: 'api_security'
    end
  end
end
```

...which would allow them to browse to `/api/v1/foo/:foo_id/users` and would send requests to the `ApiSecurityController`. Or would it go to `Api::V1::ApiSecurityController`? It frankly doesn't matter since they're all in the same namespace. I want to do it this way because I want to avoid having dozens of lines of this:

```
resources :foo do
  resources :users, controller: 'api_security'
end

resources :bar do
  resources :users, controller: 'api_security'
end
```

Using a method is easier to setup and maintain.

I'm fine as far as knowing what to do once the request gets to the controller, but it's the automatic creation of routes that I'm a little unsure of. What's the best way of handling this? The closest I've been able to find is a lot of discussion about engines but that doesn't feel appropriate because this isn't separate functionality that I want to add to my app, it's just dynamic routes that add on to existing resources.

Advice is appreciated!

Comment: http://codeconnoisseur.org/ramblings/creating-dynamic-routes-at-runtime-in-rails-4

Comment: What I'm trying to do is a bit different but I think I can `#{My app name}.routes.draw` as shown in his example to hack this together... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up building on the blog post suggested by @juanpastas, http://codeconnoisseur.org/ramblings/creating-dynamic-routes-at-runtime-in-rails-4, and tailoring it to my needs. Calling a method from the controllers ended up being a bad way to handle it. I wrote about the whole thing in my blog at http://blog.subvertallmedia.com/2014/10/08/dynamically-adding-nested-resource-routes-in-rails/ but the TL;DR:

```
# First draft, "just-make-it-work" code

# app/controllers/concerns/user_authorization.rb
module UserAuthorization
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def register_new_resource(controller_name)
      AppName::Application.routes.draw do
        puts "Adding #{controller_name}"
        namespace :api do
          namespace :v1 do
            resources controller_name.to_sym do
              resources :users, controller: 'user_security', param: :given_id
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

# application_controller.rb
include UserAuthorization

# in routes.rb
['resource1', 'resource2', 'resource3'].each { |resource| ApplicationController.register_new_resource(resource) }

# app/controllers/api/v1/user_security_controller.rb
class Api::V1::UserSecurityController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :target_id

  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  private
  attr_reader :root_resource

  def target_id
    # to get around `params[:mystery_resource_id_name]`
    @target_id ||= get_target_id
  end

  def get_target_id
    @root_resource = request.fullpath.split('/')[3].singularize
    params["#{root_resource}_id".to_sym]
  end

  def target_model
    @target_model ||= root_resource.capitalize.constantize
  end

  def given_id
    params[:given_id]
  end
end
```